# How to Send the Angular js value to PHP using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular js.Here,I am trying to send the values to PHP.Suppose, I click on that "View", then corresponding GR_ID should be send to PHP.
HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Sr No.</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat=user in users>
<td>{{user.GR_Id}}</td>
<td><a href="fetch.php?GR_ID+"={{user.GR_Id}}>VIEW</a></td> 
                    </tr>
```

Angular js:

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', []);

app.controller('listdata',function($scope){
$scope.users=[
{GR_Id:1,country:'Norway'},
{GR_Id:2,country:'Sweden'},
{GR_Id:3,country:'Denmark'}]
});
```

PHP:

```
echo $_get['GR_ID'];  // 1 or 2 or 3.
```

Please help me out.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check the href attribute: `"fetch.php?GR_ID+"={{user.GR_Id}}` results in `href="fetch.php?GR_ID+"=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref):

```
<td><a ng-href="fetch.php?GR_ID={{user.GR_Id}}">VIEW</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ng-href instead of href or the value for GR_ID won't be inserted.

[ng-href directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)